# Update steatement, ignore duplicate values

Tags: sql, oracle

```
     select case when liver is not null then 'LI' else '' end 
         || case when kidney_r is not null then ',KR' else '' end
         || case when kidney_l is not null then ',KL' else ''end
         || case when heart is not null then ',HE' else '' end
         || case when liver_domino is not null then ',LI-Dom' else '' end
         || case when lung_r is not null then ',LungR' else '' end
         || case when pancreas is not null then ',PA' else '' end
         || case when liver_split is not null then ',Lsplit' else '' end
         || case when lung_l is not null then ',LungL' else '' end
         || case when intestine is not null then ',Intestine' else '' end
         end into organType                        
from organ_pool
where organID = org_id;
```

I am getting an exception saying: `System.Data.OracleClient.OracleException: ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows` for the query above.

I am not sure why, since the `ID` is unique, and each entry is only found one time in the table. But clearly something is wrong, and I can't see it. 
How would you rewrite this statement to ignore duplicates? (assuming there

Comment: Please, check `select * from organ_pool where organID = org_id` -  do you have *exactly* `1` record?

Comment: No, there are more than 100 records

Comment: well, since `organID = org_id` condition doesn't leave *exactly one* for `into` to fecth it `into` `organType` *variable* you have an error. May be you mean a cursor, `as organType` instead of `into organType`?

Comment: Side note: `case when liver is not null then 'LI' else '' end` is equal to `Nvl2(liver, 'LI', null)`

Comment: In your question you say *"the ID is unique, and each entry is only found one time in the table"*. But in response to comment you say *"No, there are more than 100 records"*. Seems to be a contradiction there. So what is the unique key of ORGAN_POOL?

Comment: Nothing in your query is called `id`, so it doesn't matter whether or not it is unique.  You should show sample data or at least the table definition.